# Install Nuget Packages on Machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I've been installing Nuget packages and it seems that their just stick in the project. I've found a folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages, but its seems that it isn't updating the packges.
I recently installed sqlite and I went there to see if it made a change, but it didn't.
I also have the package that I want to install in .nupkg format or find a way to import it.
Is there a way to install NuGet Packages so that they stay on the Machine and not on the project folder it self?

Comment: Perhaps you want Chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=sqlite

Comment: Wow, I thought you was trolling, when you suggest that rsrsrs.

Well, since idk this Chocolatey, idk if it would help.
Since I use VS to WinApps, I would like something that I could add easily in VS projects references.

Comment: Since I don't have internet always I need to have an offline way, a way to import my .nugpkg file to each project would be also great

Comment: And I went to the Chocolatey website page for SQLite, and I'm seeing a few complaining about bugs, so it wouldn't a be fine solution for me

Comment: Do you have .Net Core SDK installed? Because you can view all your package locations with: `dotnet nuget locals –l all`. You can also configure many things about Nuget with the NuGet.config file and you can add package sources other than Nuget.org - even just a folder full of .nupkgs. Read up on it, there is a lot to know.

Comment: Yes I have the SDK installed.

I used  dotnet nuget locals all --list, and in the  C:\Users\userName\.nuget\packages, I saw I few packages.

The problem is if, I do open a new project, I can't see any package installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video solves my 90% of question, as I said above I have the .nupkg file, this videos helped me to install, it still won't be in the Machine. But it seems that Nuget get saved in the machine, not installed.

[Install Nuget from a local source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8tBjsf9Amk)

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.